# How to Grab Hotmail Contact Email Addresses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, hotmail

I am trying to retrieve user contacts in Hotmail account exactly like google+ and twitter.

What I tried so far is using getting verification code:

**wrap_scope=WL_Contacts.View**

I have traced Gogole+ and Twitter Invitations I noticed that both are using:

**wrap_scope=WL_Contacts.ViewFull**

but every time I use this parameter I receive:

```
 error_code=1017&wrap_error_reason=ExternalConsentConnectivityProblem
```

How can I get the restricted Permission `[WL_Contacts.ViewFull]`. Can any one help me out by providing some info on using the restricted apis of msn and also about applying for the scopes.

Comment: What, where, how? Please give more context for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Try To use The StesCode to buy the Service.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewFull` is a restricted scope as you mentioned. To get access you need to apply for permission. Please [Check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff749529.aspx) You could also [read this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/messengerconnect/thread/445ce7da-0e07-4d22-9b38-0de2908daddb) which talks about your problem and possible solutions. Good luck!

Comment: can you provide me more information of how to obtain this permission?